# Detect if the php script is called from schell_execute or is being run manually

Tags: php, debugging, shell-exec

We have a case where our handler is being called from an shell_execute. Our Debugger then thinks he is being called from the user from the cmd directly and outputs true. we need to handle on it. any idea how?

```
public static function canDebug($enviroment = 'any')
{
    if ($enviroment == "sql" && self::$disableSqlDebug) {
        return false;
    }
    if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
        if (isset($_SERVER['TERM'])) {
            //The script was run from a manual invocation on a shell
            return (($enviroment == 'any' || $enviroment == 'console') && !self::$disableCliDebug);
        } else {
            //The script was run from the crontab entry
            return (($enviroment == 'any' || $enviroment == 'cron') && !self::$disableCliDebug);
        }
    } else {
        if (!isset(self::$mergedConfig['debug']['allowedIPRanges']))
            return false;
        return (self::isIPAllowedToDebug(self::getClientIPAddress()) && ($enviroment == 'any' || $enviroment == 'webOnly'));
    }
}
```

The promlem si that the server TERM var is set in shell_exec runs. and it returns true on that part. we need to recognise if it is manual.

Comment: Check what uid is running the process? Pass an additional parameter in your shell_exec call that makes this discernible to the script itself?

Comment: That is my end hack solution. would not like it very much in case someone else uses the script.